# Highcharts: How to Place Y-axis title next to first marker?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am developing application using angular and very new to this high charts. I have requirement where we should place the title next to first marker of bar chart and values are dynamic . here is the existing code https://jsfiddle.net/manoj_rejinthala1510/698mhz2k/3/ .

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
       },
      yAxis: {
        
        title: {                    
            text: '<b>Target</b>',
            rotation: 0           
        }
    },
    

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
    type: 'area',
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    },
    {
    type: 'line',
        data: [50,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

I want to achieve like i mention in attachment.  [image] .

Could any one help me to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place the title dynamically in the `render` event, for example:

```
    chart: {
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
                    title = yAxis.axisTitle,
                    firstTick = yAxis.ticks[yAxis.tickPositions[1]];

                title.attr({
                    y: firstTick.label.xy.y
                });

            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/30c26hgx/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: your solution works perfect but i have one more issue when i change the first value of bar chart and its not moving label position  https://jsfiddle.net/manoj_rejinthala1510/x9n1s8m4/  . Could you please help me with this

Comment: Hi @Manoj Rejinthala, I thought that you wanted to place the title next to the first y-axis tick. Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/03j6eh5n/